# Calculating transmittance LED

Tags: led, optics

I am solving the following problem:

> Consider a GaAs emitter. Calculate the transmittance for the interface GaAs/glass/air. Assume near
> normal incidence. GaAs: n= 3.4; glass: n=1.5. Answer: 81.6%

My attempt:

I know that the reflectance and transmittance are given by:

\begin{align}
R&=\left\lvert\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}\right\rvert\\
T&=1-R
\end{align}

Then I calculated for both interfaces GaAs/glass and glass/air

\begin{align}
R_1&=0.387755102\\
T_1&=0.612244898\\
R_2&=0.2\\
T_2&=0.8
\end{align}

I don't know to relate both transmittances to obtain the global one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure you use the correct equations? Because for normal incidence, it is:
$$R={\left\lvert\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}\right\rvert\\}^2$$

$$T=1-R$$

[Reference - Fresnel Equation for Reflectance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations)

Based on above equations, for GaAs-Glass interface, you will get -
$$R_1=0.15$$
$$T_1=0.85$$

For Glass-Air interface, you will get -
$$R_2=0.04$$
$$T_2=0.96$$

So mathematically, the effective transmittance should be -

$$T_{eff}=T_1 \times T_2 = 0.816 = 81.6 \% $$

therefore effective reflectance should be -
$$R_{eff}=1-T_{eff}=0.184=18.4\%$$

If you plug in the relationship between \$R\$ and \$T\$, you can derive relation for effective reflectance as well -
$$R_{eff}=1-T_{eff}$$
$$R_{eff}=1-(T_1\times T_2)$$
$$R_{eff}=1-((1-R_1)\times (1-R_2))$$
$$\implies R_{eff}=R_1+R_2-R1.R2$$